# Stacked Barplot in R: Correctly Formatting Data

Tags: r

I have a data frame of political contributions, broken down by year-month and party (sum is the aggregate amount given by my population, median is the median contribution given):

```
> head(contribs)
        DATE PARTY  SUM MEDIAN
  1 Feb 2001   DEM  250    250
  2 Mar 2001   DEM 4000   1000
  3 Mar 2001   REP 1000   1000
  4 Apr 2001   DEM 1000   1000 
  5 Apr 2001   GRE  500    250
  6 May 2001   DEM 1250    625
```

I'm trying to format the data such that I can display it in a stacked bar plot, with `DATE` on the x-axis and `SUM` on the y-axis, with `PARTY` as the variable that is stacked (for example, at `Mar 2001` on the x-axis, I would like a bar of height 4000 in blue stacked underneath a bar of height 1000.

Ultimately, I would like to overlay the contribution medians by party as a line chart, but I'm sure I can figure that out once I do this.

I've tried an array of `barplot(contribs)`, `barplot(as.matrix(contribs))`, `melt(contribs)`, and I guess that I'm just not correctly understanding the way the data needs to be formatted.

I take that, for the stacked bar plot that I want to produce, I need the data to be formatted as such, with the `DATE` values as the column names:

```
      Feb 2001  Mar 2001  Apr 2001 ...
 DEM  250       4000      1000
 REP  0         1000      0
 GRE  0         0         500
```

However, I'm not sure how to wrangle the data into such a format. Does anyone have any tips? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(reshape2)
library(zoo) 
 df1 <- transform(df[order(as.yearmon(df$DATE)),], 
                   DATE=factor(DATE, levels=unique(DATE)))
 m1 <- acast(df1, PARTY~DATE, value.var='SUM', fill=0)
 m1
 #    Feb 2001 Mar 2001 Apr 2001 May 2001
 #DEM      250     4000     1000     1250
 #GRE        0        0      500        0
 #REP        0     1000        0        0

 barplot(m1, col=4:2)
 legend('topright', legend=row.names(m1), fill=4:2)
```

[image]

#### Update

```
 par(oma=c(0,0,2,0))
 barplot(rep(NA, ncol(m1)), ylim=c(0, max(m1)+2000), axes=FALSE)
 barplot(m1, col=4:2, add=TRUE)   
 abline(v=1.9)
 legend('topright', legend=row.names(m1), fill=4:2)
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(DATE = c("Feb 2001", "Mar 2001", "Mar 2001", "Apr 2001", 
 "Apr 2001", "May 2001"), PARTY = c("DEM", "DEM", "REP", "DEM", 
"GRE", "DEM"), SUM = c(250L, 4000L, 1000L, 1000L, 500L, 1250L
), MEDIAN = c(250L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 250L, 625L)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"PARTY", "SUM", "MEDIAN"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Works great! An additional question, though: any idea how I might add a vertical abline, say, at "Mar 2001"? ```abline(as.Date(...))``` and ```abline(as.yearmon(as.Date(...)))``` don't error, but don't display.

Comment: @ahp Updated with the `abline`

Answer (score 2):

Could as well melt the data and use `ggplot` to plot it.

Melt the data

```
library(reshape2)
mcont <- melt(contribs[-4]) # ignore "MEDIAN" column
```

Sort the data set by date (if not sorted yet- not in your specific case)

```
indx <- order(as.Date(paste(mcont$DATE, "01"), format = "%b %Y %d"))
mcont <- mcont[indx, ]
```

Plotting the data using `ggplot` (ggplot provides default colors, but you can set your own colors)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mcont, aes(DATE, value, fill = PARTY)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = unique(contribs$DATE)) + # Sort labels according to the correct order 
  scale_fill_manual(values = 4:2) # Select your own colors if you want
```

[image]